# Want to add share button symbol on my app

Tags: android

Hi I have done following in my app
I am able to share my content but it comes from menuinflator not the symbol

[Image shows that menuinflator has share button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLUgr.png)

If i click on share button ,I can share ,  But I want have the share symbol ,How to do it ?
I have read the following link 
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html
but symbol doesn't comes .

My code is below

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    Menu xyz;
    TextView t1 ;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate menu resource file.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_filexml, menu);

        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
        this.xyz = menu;

        // Return true to display menu
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_item_share :
                String code = " ";
                code = this.t1.getText().toString();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
                sendIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", code);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Menu resource file (menu_filexml.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

</menu>
```

This code allows me to work as given in images but sharing symbol is not coming

Comment: @Enzokie Ya i mean the sharing icon on top right side of app

Comment: You need to add an icon in your drawable folder and do something like this `android:icon="@drawable/my_menu_item_icon"`

Comment: @Enzokie its not working

Answer (score 0):

you need to use custom view for your menu item. just create an layout file and name it "my_item_custom_view" and put your icon as 'ImageView' in it then assign the layout file like below:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/menu_share"
android:title="share"
app:showAsAction="always"
app:actionLayout="@layout/my_item_custom_view"/>
```